# extending codeigniter controllers and separate business logic

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

How can i separate my business logic away from my controllers in Codeigniter. I am using HMVC with Phills template library. Here is my current setup.

//Application/core/MY_controller.php

```
class My_controller extends MX_controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
  }
}

class dCommerce extends MY_controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     #Some of my code that shares the entire app, ex: login
  }
}
```

Now in controller i want something like this
//Application/controllers/sales_order.php

```
class Sales_order extends dCommerce extends dSales_Order
{ 
  //dSales_Order have all my core APP logic
}
```

i know that multiple inheritance is not possible with PHP, However how can i separate the logic from controllers ?

`Sales_order` will contain all my framework based logic (depends app) ex, validation and the core class `dSales_Order` will have the core app logic ex. Save,Create etc

A sample would be like this ...

```
    class dSales_Order
    {
      function save( $sales_order_id , $details )
      {
        //blah blah codes and APP logic, too much of math 
        //and then save to DB, this class will be framework Independed
        //only pure php code 
      }
   }
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: maybe i didn't understand you fully. why do you want to extend a class that handles business logic from a controller?

Comment: the main reason is that i want to change my framework (but not now), the controller class will have framework depended codes, but my core class will only have pure php code. Ex. in 2 frameworks they will have 2 types of validation class, but still my APP logic same on the core class. Also it gives many flexibility (atleast in case of CI setup) ex. You cannot call controller inside another controller, then how can i call the controller logic from outside of controller ?

Comment: I used to separate my logic into libraries and just call them from your controllers to get the required functionality. Another way which seems to be the norm for models is to use them for the logic and database. Then just have light controllers that pass requests to the models or libraries. Either way it separates them from the logic!

Comment: @micb technically it works ... but i need them out of libs. Simply because the core class have nothing to do with the framework( ex. Codeigniter ), infact technically i can do this by adding one line of code `include("dSales_Order")` at the top of the page. But its not the CI way of doing things :(

Comment: why don't you build a 'Model' class called dsales_Order to handle your app logic (save, create etc.). and then create an instance of it inside the controller (Sales_Order).

Comment: @om_deshpande I already described that. If i put it inside a `Codeigniter Model` then i cannot say the word `CORE`. Infact this is the normal behavior of any CI project which i dont want to follow.My case is very rare case and very hard to explain. Just assume that our project is doing in multiple frameworks. Ex. Zend,CI,YII etc. Now i cannot use any of framework based components (ex. I cannot use CI model inside YII without a rewrite ) and thats why i proposed the word CORE. Hope its clear.

Comment: ok, i think i understand where you're coming from now. here is what i believe you should do. build a list of objects (i.e. sales,customer,employee etc.). code all these objects in core php. then, use the framework models as an additional layer in between the controller and your objects. this way you can move your objects files to any framework that you want OR you can even make accessible via a REST API to multiple frameworks at once. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for my bad English.

I hope your doubts is an OOPS and PHP related. I cannot understand your full requirements.

Even I recommend you to go with new PHP concept called [`traits`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) or [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i understand where you're coming from now; after exchanging a few comments.

Here is what i believe you should do:

- Build a list of objects (i.e. sales,customer,employee etc.).
- Code all these objects in core PHP.
- Then, use the framework models as an additional layer in between the controller and your objects.
- You can move your objects files to any framework that you want.
- You can even make accessible via a REST API to multiple frameworks at once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is what i need and i am asking the best way to do this. I normally hates `includes` in CI Controllers. Additionally i believe that its not easy to extend CI database class :(

Comment: is a mistake to change the core folder, it is not recommended